# Regex for matching string between a space and a character

Tags: regex

I have a string like `where position = 'down'`

I need to match just the `position` part of the string.

I also need to match `position` in the case where there is no space between `position` and the `=` the string could be like `where position='down'` for example

Also, the text before the word `position` can change. So essentially I just need to match the word before the `=`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
\S+(?=\s*=)
```

[Demo Here](https://regex101.com/r/xAAtW2/1)

---

Explanation:

- `\S+` looks for 1 or more non-space characters (could be replaced with `\w+` or `[A-Za-z]+` depending on what you want.)
- `(?=...)` is a lookahead group, meaning it makes sure its contents follow our match

  - `\s*=` will look for zero or more space characters, followed by the `=` character

Answer (score 1):

```
(\S+)\s*=
```

this should capture the word "position" regardless of there being spaces.

tested using regex101.com .